# Remove First and Last Character C++

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, erase-remove-idiom

How to remove first and last character from std::string, I am already doing the following code.

But this code only removes the last character

```
m_VirtualHostName = m_VirtualHostName.erase(m_VirtualHostName.size() - 1)
```

How to remove the first character also?

Comment: That code will go boom if the string is empty.

Comment: What type is m_VirtualHostName?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so i must validate first, if VirtualHostName is not empty.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Well, you could [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) the first character too (note that `erase()` modifies the string):

```
m_VirtualHostName.erase(0, 1);
m_VirtualHostName.erase(m_VirtualHostName.size() - 1);
```

But in this case, a simpler way is to take a substring:

```
m_VirtualHostName = m_VirtualHostName.substr(1, m_VirtualHostName.size() - 2);
```

Be careful to validate that the string actually has at least two characters in it first...

Comment: it will crash, if im only have 2 characters ?

Comment: @Putra: Yes. C++ is not particularly friendly that way ;-) **Edit**: No, I misread your comment. It will crash if you have *less than* two characters (0 or 1).

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin It will when you have no or 1 character in the string. It's documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase). Only execute the second line when [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns at least 1.

Comment: While the `substr` looks cleaner in code it will trigger an additional memory allocation (which might or not be important). Also the first erase might be simpler if stated as: `str.erase(str.end()-1); str.erase(str.begin());`

Answer (score 11):

My BASIC interpreter chops beginning and ending quotes with

```
str->pop_back();
str->erase(str->begin());
```

Of course, I *always* expect well-formed BASIC style strings, so I will abort with failed `assert` if not:

`assert(str->front() == '"' && str->back() == '"');`

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
str = str.substr(1,str.length()-2);
```

And to further what others were saying about @mhadhbi_issam code, here is a better approach:

```
void trimmed(std::string &str)
{
  int begI = 0,endI = str.length();
  if (endI == begI)
    return;
  std::string::iterator beg = str.begin();
  std::string::iterator end = str.end();
  end--;
  while (isspace(*beg) || isspace(*end))
  {
    if (isspace(*beg)) { beg++; begI++; }
    if (isspace(*end)) { end--; endI--; }
  }
  str = str.substr(begI,(endI-begI));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string trimmed(std::string str ) {
if(str.length() == 0 ) { return "" ; }
else if ( str == std::string(" ") ) { return "" ; } 
else {
    while(str.at(0) == ' ') { str.erase(0, 1);}
    while(str.at(str.length()-1) == ' ') { str.pop_back() ; }
    return str ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: this function make the string trimmed , it is equivalent to QString::trimmed(QString) , it delete the white space from end and front , do whatever it need to modify it to make it do the job ...............

Comment: The while-loops (especially the front one) will make this quite inefficient. Search for the last/first blank and execute a single erase for each.

Comment: you can put the two condition in same while : as two condtion using AND  or one while with if condition with break .

Comment: Ok, so not only is this a code-snipped without any explanation or comment on why one would write it like that, this also does NOT do what was asked but also the action it performs is horribly inefficient.

For those wondering: This code would do SINGLE erases on the front of the string until there is no leading space, then do single erases on the pack of the string.... a trim-function that is really really slow.